# Apache Camel - Kafka component - single producer multiple consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am creating two apache camel (blueprint XML) kafka projects, one is kafka-producer which accepts requests and stores it in kafka server, and other is kafka-consumer which picks ups messages from kafka server and processes them.

This setup is working fine for single topic and single consumer. However how do I create separate consumer groups within same kafka topic? How to route multiple consumer specific messages within same topic inside different consumer groups? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite general as it's not very clear what's the problem you are trying to solve, therefore it's hard to understand if there's a better way to implement the solution.

Anyway let's start by saying that, as far as I can understand, you are looking for a Selective Consumer (EIP) which is something that's not supported out-of-the-box by Kafka and Consumer API. Selective Consumer can choose what message to pick from the queue or topic based on specific selectors' values that are put in advance by a producer. This feature must be implemented in the message broker as well, but kafka has not such a capability.

Kafka does implement a hybrid solution between pure pub/sub and queue. That being said, what you can do is subscribing to the topic with one or more consumer groups (more on that later) and filter out all messages you're not interested in, by inspecting messages themselves. In the messaging and EIP world, this pattern is known as Array of Filters. As you can imagine this happen after the message has been broadcasted to all subscribers; therefore if that solution does not fit your requirements or context, then you can think of implementing a Content Based Router which is intended to dispatch the message to a subset of consumers only under your centralized control (this would imply intermediate consumer-specific channels that could be other Kafka topics or seda/VM queues, of course).

Moving to the second question, here is the official Kafka Component website: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html.
In order to create different consumer groups, you just have to define multiple routes each of them having a dedicated groupId. By adding the groupdId property, you will inform the Consumer Group coordinators (that reside in Kafka brokers) about the existence of multiple separated groups of consumers and brokers will use those in order to discriminate and treat them separately (by sending them a copy of each log message stored in the topic)...

Here is an example:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("kafka:myTopic?brokers={{kafkaBootstrapServers}}" +
                 "&groupId=myFirstConsumerGroup"
            .log("Message received by myFirstConsumerGroup : ${body}");

    from("kafka:myTopic?brokers={{kafkaBootstrapServers}}" +
                 "&groupId=mySecondConsumerGroup"
            .log("Message received by mySecondConsumerGroup : ${body}");

}
```

As you can see, I created two routes in the same RouteBuilder, not to say in the same Java process. That's a very bad design decision in most of the use cases I can think of, because there's no single responsibility, segregated concerns and they will not scale. But again, it depends on your requirements/context.
Out of completeness, please consider taking a look at all other Kafka Component properties, as there may be many other configurations of your interest such as the number of consumer threads per group.
I tried to stay high level, in order to initiate the discussion... I'll edit my answer in case of new updates from you. Hope I helped!